# Rails Bootstrap popover won't toggle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap popover to toggle.

JS code:

```
$('#post_description').popover('toggle')
```

Form code:

```
    <%= f.input :description, :label => 'Description', :input_html => {:rows => '10', :class => "span8", "data-content" =>'Hey', "data-title" => 'TEXTILE'} %>
```

The popover shows up when I mouse over the field, but goes away when I move the cursor off the field.  Shouldn't toggle show the popover when I click and close it on the second click?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens with just `$('#post_description').popover();`?

Comment: It acts the same. It's like the toggle isn't working.